# Leiningen can't resolve dependency containing a dash

Tags: maven, clojure, dependency-management, leiningen

I'm referencing only one single extra dependency in the Leiningen project file:

```
(defproject foo-bar "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
                 [com.github.sharispe/slib-sml "0.9"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]                                  
                 ])
```

`lein test` complains:

```
lein test
Could not find artifact com.github.sharispe:slib:pom:0.9 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
Tests failed.
```

Note that the pom's artifact ID is incorrect, the `-sml` part is dropped... The jar is in the central, of course:

```
lein search slib-sml
Searching over Artifact ID...
 == Showing page 1 / 1
[com.github.sharispe/slib-sml "0.9"] Semantic measures library
```

Does someone have any idea why does lein seem to drop the `-sml` part of the artifact ID? I know dashes are not conformant to the clj naming conventions, but in case of external dependencies, this should just work.

(By the way:`lein --version
Leiningen 2.5.0 on Java 1.7.0_67 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`) -- and yes, I have a working internet connection :)

Comment: The `com.github.sharispe/slib-sml` artifact lists `com.github.sharispe/slib` as its parent. I suspect that lein is trying to fetch the parent POM during dependency resolution and failing when the parent is not available.

Comment: You're right and I'm stupid, thanks :) This is a problem with the artifact, not with leiningen.

Comment: You might work around it by grabbing the parent POM and stashing it in a local repo inside your project (and using the :local-repo key in project.clj)

Answer (score 1):

As Alex pointed out, this is a problem with the artifact itself, not with leiningen.